# In Neo4j how can I create relationships between one node an a collection of other nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph containing some nodes with `:SubSystem` labels. I want to add a new node with a `:Document` label and create relationships with each of the existing `:SubSystem` nodes.

When I execute this statement:

```
MATCH (s:SubSystem)
CREATE (d:Document {title:'New Document'})
CREATE (d)-[:DEPICTS]->(s);
```

I was surprised when Neo4j created a new `:Document` node for each `:SubSystem`. I have 12 sub-systems, so I ended up with 12 new documents each related to one sub-system. I would have expected this behavior had I written:

```
MATCH (s:SubSystem)
CREATE (:Document {title:'New Document'})-[:DEPICTS]->(s);
```

But I was expecting that separating the `CREATE` clauses would create 1 document then create relationships between that document and each of the sub-systems.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work as I was expecting.

EDIT:

I found a solution. This statement does what I wanted, but I still think my original attempt should have worked.

```
CREATE (d:Document {title:'New Document'})
WITH d MATCH (s:SubSystem) CREATE (d)-[:DEPICTS]->(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `MATCH` clause generates one or more result rows (or aborts the query if no results are found). A subsequent read/write clause would be executed once *per row*. Rearranging the order of the clauses, as you did, is one way to work around that (when possible).

Comment: If I have multiple match clauses that return one node each, followed by a create clause, Neo4j will only create one new node, not one for each node returned by the match clauses.

Comment: That is a very special case. But that case is also covered by my answer.

Comment: Your answer brings me no closer to understanding the problem. I still feel that if I create one node then create relationships to a list of nodes then the relationships should all lead back to the one node I created.